# Open Android App from Browser using HTML Link or JavaScript, not Java

Tags: javascript, android

I know, I can do this with a AndroidManifest.xml file... but I do not have access to it!

Also, I could do it in Java... but I am not able to manipulate the target app.

I need something in HTML, Javascript or PHP that can accomplish what I need:

I have a website (mimmsy.com) and it contains Play buttons which launch a player on the desktop and should launch an app on a mobile device.

Things are great on everything except Android.

I am trying to launch the Netflix app (com.netflix.mediaclient)... anyone done this before? Is there even a way to do what I need? I found an example that uses an <a> link to send [android intents](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) to the phone, but it was limited in its explanation and so I was not able to customize it correctly for my situation (see HTML below)...

I can get the play.google.com store to load and perform a search for the netflix app, but I do not know how to pass the action I need in the intent URI.

Here is what I have so far:

`href="intent://start/#Intent;scheme=netflix;package=com.netflix.mediaclient;action=title_activity_movie;end"> Launch Netflix Player App`

Any insights or links to a beginner tutorial would be HUGELY appreciated.

UPDATE: I understand that the app needs to allow itself to be launched. I am really hoping someone else has accomplished this in the way I need to and can tell me how they did it. I am a Netflix developer, but they are not exactly forethcoming with the docs.

Answer (score 1):

If the Android app that you want to launch doesn't have an intent filter that recognizes a specific URL scheme (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2958870/1253844)), then you simply cannot launch it from the web browser.

You can launch the Play Store from the browser because the Play Store app has such an intent filter defined.

I cannot say whether or not the Netflix app has such an intent filter defined. However, if it does, it is undocumented and subject to change without warning.

**Edit:**
From the looks of the link you posted, you are currently trying to use the [Android Intents with Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents) feature.

While this is a better way to implement this feature than the older method I linked to previously, it still isn't possible if the app doesn't have an intent filter with `<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>` defined in the manifest.

Comment: Any answer in Java and XML doesn't help me. I need something in HTML/Javascript since I have no way of directly altering the Netflix app. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I know what you want. What I'm telling you is that it isn't possible if the app doesn't already support it and you don't have the ability modify the application.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying. I am hoping someone else will have already sussed the info I need to do it as well... I am sure I am not the only person who would want to do this in this manner.